# Solace Subscriptions that are a list

Tags: list, wildcard, subscription, solace

I have read this page about solace wildcards and had a question:
https://docs.solace.com/PubSub-Basics/Wildcard-Charaters-Topic-Subs.htm

I have a dynamic topic like this

produce/apple/seedless/color

I want to get in this case a list of apples. I want to get all the gala, delicious, ... apples.

I know I can create individual subscribers for each apple type but in the base of my data there could be hundreds and I only want a subset of them. Is it possible to pass in a list of subscriptions for the apple fields? This will be a subscription created on a physical queue listening to dynamic topics created programatically based on the message payload.

example of the subscription I want:
produce/galla,seedless,delicious/seedless/color

not 3 subscriptions:
produce/galla/seedless/color
produce/seedless/seedless/color
produce/delicious/seedless/color

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Revisit your topic structure.

Does produce/> contain only apples?  Then use produce/> but probably best to rename it apples/.

If produce contains apples and oranges, add a topic level:
produce/apples/...
produce/oranges/...

Then you can just subscribe to 
produce/apples/>

Comment: I would but this is s a topic structure defined by a different organization and I have to use this format. I am really hoping I can add a delimited list of subscribers somehow because if not we are talking of having roughly 1000 subscribers per queues. Any insight if solace supports this? I can not find any evidence that they support this.

Comment: Queues can subscribe to multiple topics, and you can combine this with wildcards:
produce/galla/>, produce/delicious/>, produce/seedless/>
All on one queue.